# How To Make a command with AppleScript to Terminal to free ram space OSX ML

Tags: macos, memory, terminal, applescript, osx-mountain-lion

I'd like to write an AppleScript command that can run Terminal and write "purge" , press return and then cmd-q.

I tried this way:

tell application "terminal"
keystroke ???????????
(I don't know how to use keystrokes commands!)
end tell

I'd like to compose this command with AppleScript to free RAM space only starting a script without third party apps.

Answer (score 1):

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate

    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "sudo"
        keystroke return
    end tell

end tell
```

or the answer by Lauri, which does the same thing without showing the Terminal or having to activate it.

Answer (score 0):

Applications that free inactive memory are a huge scam. Read some of the questions linked [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/72033/how-does-memory-management-work-in-mac-os-x/72036#72036). But if you really have to do it, use `do shell script`:

```
do shell script "purge"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Shell scripting (runs the command without even opening Terminal, best option)
2. Keystrokes, as you have said

Shell scripting:

```
do shell script "purge"
```

Keystrokes:

```
tell app "Terminal" to activate
tell app "System Events" to keystroke "purge"
tell app "System Events" to keystroke return
tell app "Terminal" to quit
```